# Cleaning oldest maximum rows

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgresql table into which I'm storing "session" records. Those sessions sometimes get created very quickly (sometimes up to a few hundred a second). I obviously cannot let the table grow indefinitely. So I have a daemon that periodically sweeps the table, imposing an externally configurable limit on the size.

When the number of records exceeds the limit, I want to pull out the oldest records (using the limit value), write them to a separate (non-relational) log file in text form, then delete them from the table. What I'm doing currently works, but with a high limit, it is very slow. My current query is something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM sessions ORDER BY modified DESC OFFSET 1000000 LIMIT 10000;
```

My program then logs those least-recently-modified records to the offline history and then does a separate SQL `DELETE` to drop the rows. The problem is that doing the query above if I have say 1000010 records takes on the order of 25-30 seconds to obtain those 10 records. Creating an index on the `modified` field does not seem to have any appreciable effect so I assume postgres is creating a temporary dataset somewhere before it counts out the first 1 million records and then excludes them.

Is there a better way to do this so as to obtain the same result? I essentially just want to obtain the oldest "`count(*) - N`" rows of the table.

(I now realize I could first do a separate query to obtain `count(*)` of the table, then reverse the `ORDER BY` clause of the query and then only use `LIMIT` but that seems kludgy. That will be my fallback, but I prefer to do what I've stated above directly if possible.)

Comment: 1) Can you run an `EXPLAIN` on your query to determine whether postgresql is actually hitting the index you've created? 2) Are you comfortable selecting all records where `modified` is before a given timestamp? This _may_ hit an index better.

Comment: So, turns out I had oversimplified my example. There was more to the issue than I thought (I had omitted a WHERE clause above that turned out to be critical although I had not thought it was relevant). Thanks  to @AndrewRueckert for the suggestion to run EXPLAIN. I learned a lot from that (it had required a sequential scan among other things) and did essentially as you suggested: first a SELECT to determine a reference timestamp, then a reversed-order SELECT to find the rows older than the timestamp. With the new flow plus an index, it's down to a couple of seconds for the typical case.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is offset, since you do offset 1000000 you do a lot of scan and this makes the index not used.  I do not know how much is your table sise but why do not you partition your table using modified date. in this case you will know exactly which partition you need to access and delete data form.

Comment: I think the problem is lack of keys.